# Painfully slow at selecting bones in pose mode

Tags: rigging, bones, pose-mode

I have to wait for 5+seconds every time I select a bone before it's selected. Is my PC just bad or am I bad?

my specs should be pretty good, can't remember them because I am a scrub

Answer (score 5):

I Noticed the same issue with Blender 2.79c. Even very simple models were presenting lags in bone selection. 
What solved it for me was going to "user preferences->System" and changing the "Selection" option from "automatic" to "OpenGL Occlusion Queries".
Hope this helps.